# how to dispose clearly the tables in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just found the PHPMyAdmin Designer view, which is very useful to me. 
On the other hand, is there a functionality which makes it possible to 
arrange the tables without them being one on the other and to keep the 
disposition ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag the tables around by grabbing on the top bar of each one: [image: Top of a table]

You can minimize a table by using the little arrow on the left side of that title bar as well: [image: Minimize]

If you've configured your [phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) (or allowed it to automatically configure), you can use the fan-out menu on the side of Designer to save the page layout, so you can get your layout back when returning to Designer (changes are not automatically saved, you'll have to manually press the Save button):

[image: foldout menu]